# ios change color of item of navbar when present event kit

Tags: ios, xcode, navbar, eventkit

I am using  in order to add event on my calendar via my mobile application. 
What I want to do is to change the color of the items of the navbar (CANCEL and DONE) please check the image below:[image]

any suggestions?

Comment: you can use the  appearance .  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And if you are presenting `UIViewController` then use below code:

Create a `UIBarButtonItem`

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonTapped:)];

[barButton setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

And if you are using `Apple` provided `UIViewController` then this code:

```
  UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        [controller setDelegate:self];
        [controller setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary | UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
        [controller.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: It is not the customized viewController(Apple provided VC) to call it.  When you are presenting there is no use of accessing self.navigationController. It will be nil.

Comment: I was already using this code on viewDidLoad but the secret was to put it on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions! Thanks :) that did the change

Comment: How will you add it to the apple provided VC? You also need toolbar for it